# Cannot hook up an event

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to install event from class BasicLaser in a class BlueShip, so basically this event will be fired every n number of time units.
Here is the class BlueShip which is "connected" to a sprite in unity:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Timers;
using System;

    public class BlueShip : MonoBehaviour
    {
        enum LaserTypes { BASIC_LASER };
        private float speed_ = 100f;
        private List<GameObject> laser_ = new List<GameObject>();
        private GameObject currentLaser_;
        private Transform transform_;
        private Vector3 currentPosition_;
        private bool isElapsed_ = true;
        // Use this for initialization
        void Start()
        {
            transform_ = transform;
            /*Basic laser is the default and it's guaranteed to be installed at the beginning of the game*/
            laser_.Add((GameObject)Resources.Load("BasicLaser"));
            currentLaser_ = laser_[(int)LaserTypes.BASIC_LASER];
            laser_[0].GetComponent<BasicLaser>().timerElapsed += new TimerElapsed (BasicLaser_timerElapsed);    
//HERE I'M adding observer to this event but look for line named *2 in class BasicLaser


        }  

        public void BasicLaser_timerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {/*this is supposed to react to event timerElapsed in BasicLaser*/
            isElapsed_ = true;
        }


        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            var amtToMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed_ * Time.deltaTime;
            transform_.Translate(Vector3.right * amtToMove);
            /*Those below set the position for laser to be instantiated at*/
            currentPosition_.x = transform_.position.x;
            currentPosition_.y = transform_.position.y + (this.transform.localScale.y / 2) + currentLaser_.transform.localScale.y;
            currentPosition_.z = transform_.position.z;


            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            {
                if (isElapsed_)
                {
                    var t = Instantiate(laser_[(int)LaserTypes.BASIC_LASER], currentPosition_, Quaternion.identity);
                    isElapsed_ = false;
                }

            }

        }
    }


//BasicLaser class  which is "connected" to a BasicLaser prefab in unity
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System;
    public delegate void TimerElapsed(object sender,EventArgs e);
        public class BasicLaser : MonoBehaviour
        {

            private float speed_ = 500f;
            private static uint frequency_ = 2;//the frequency with which this laser can be fired
            private static Stopwatch stopWatch_ = new Stopwatch();

            public event TimerElapsed timerElapsed;//HERE IS THE EVENT

            public uint Frequency
            {
                get { return frequency_; }
                set { frequency_ = value; }
            }

            private Transform transform_;
            // Use this for initialization
            void Start()
            {
                transform_ = transform;
                stopWatch_.Start();

            }



            // Update is called once per frame
            void Update()
            {
                var amtToMove = speed_ * Time.deltaTime;
                transform_.Translate(Vector3.up * amtToMove);
            var t = stopWatch_.Elapsed.Milliseconds;
                if (t > frequency_)
                {
                    stopWatch_ = new Stopwatch();
                    stopWatch_.Start();
                    if (timerElapsed != null)//*2 THIS IS ALWAYS NULL!!!  
     even though I've hooked it in BlueShip class, what's going on?

                    {
                        timerElapsed(this, EventArgs.Empty);//raises the event
                    }
                }

                if (transform.position.y >= Screen.height)
                {
                    Destroy(gameObject);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Erm, what's your question exactly?

Comment: #TonyHopkinson the question is, why I'm having timerElapsed event declared in BasicLaser always null even though I'm hooking an observer to this event in class BlueShip. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Have you attached a debugger and stepped through this?

Comment: Ah got you, so the += seems not to be occurring. First thoughts would to make sure GetComponent is returning the instance you think it is, and to check the way you've declared the event, and last bt not least some other bit of code isn't -= it somewhere.

Comment: #TonyHopkinson hi, GetComponent is returning correct obj. I know that because of the event type in the returning object is the one I defined and intellisense detects it. There definitely isn't -= anywhere in the code. The code I've provided in the OP is the whole code I've got.

Comment: @smallB Way too much code posted. Reduce it to the smallest that explains and repro's your problem.  You'll probably find the problem just doing that.

Comment: @JohnArlen this is the minimal amount of code. If you cannot be bothered, that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the Console or log file and tell us if you're getting any errors in `BlueShip`'s `Start` method.  Also use `Debug.Log` and look in the log files to see if any of the objects are null when they shouldn't be. (e.g. `Debug.Log (currentLaser_);`)

I think this is your problem:

```
(GameObject)Resources.Load("BasicLaser")
```

This gives your the object in your Assets/Resources folder called "BasicLaser", which (assuming it exists at all) is probably a prefab.  The `GameObject` you can get here is not the same as a `GameObject` you might have in the scene.  You should either be instantiating this prefab and then attaching to that instantiated object's event, or you should be referring to a `BasicLaser` that already exists in your scene, by changing the line to this: `laser_.Add((GameObject)GameObject.Find ("BasicLaser"));` (if the name of the `GameObject` with the `BasicLaser` component is `"BasicLaser"`).